# Kernel and OS Versioning

Tags: 16.04, kernel, updates

Can you run 4.15 kernel on Ubuntu 16.04? The broader question is what is the relationship between kernel versioning and OS versioning? When do you need to upgrade your OS to run a new kernel? I am pretty sure I'm running kernel 4.15 on Ubuntu 16.04 but that doesn't make sense to me since Ubuntu 18.04 uses Kernel 4.15 also.

Comment: The other question is similar but it doesn't directly answer the question of when do you need to upgrade OS for new kernel and if 4.15 runs on 16.04 or the relationship between kernel and OS so I don't think this question is a duplicate.

Comment: It does answer these questions. I can shortly answer again. You NEVER need to "upgrade OS for new kernel" and yes, the 4.15 kernel "runs" on 16.04. If you read the link carefully, you'll find out why.

Comment: Thank you - I see. So then why would I upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 when I can run the same kernel on 16.04? Just for a new gui?

Comment: People select OS not for "running a specific kernel".

Comment: But most of the OS's capabilities are determined by the kernel- so what is the allure of a new version of the OS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90271/discussion-between-moriarty-and-pilot6).

Comment: That is a wrong statement. OS capabilities are 99.999% same on all kernels.